# href link not working when the website is deployed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, materialize

I have this piece of code that works like a charm when i'm running it on local.

As soon as i deployed it, the link become broken.

```
      <ul className="sidenav" id='mobile-nav'>
          <li className="nav-item"><a href="/page1">Page1</a></li>
 <li className="nav-item"><a href="/page2">Page2</a></li>
 <li className="nav-item"><a href="/page3">Page3</a></li>
 <li className="nav-item"><a href="/page4">Page4</a></li>
                    <li className="nav-item"><a href="/page5">Page5</a></li>
                </ul>
```

when deployed i get

```
The requested URL /page1.html was not found on this server.
```

Is there a way to fix this and make the href work again and redirect me ?

**Edit**

Even if i refresh the page on mywebsite.com/Page1 i get 404 not found

but i can access to mywebsite.com/Page1 after going to mywebsite.com/index.html and click on the redirect button to the Page1

Am i doing something wrong ?

**Edit2**

Guys i Found it :

I forget to add

```
    RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

Comment: you should write full file path with extension. ex page1.html

Comment: did you check capital letters? I know my local webserver doesn't care if i name the file Page1.html and link to it with page1.html but my deployment server shits bricks and goes full defcon 1 and errors all

Comment: @manan5439 please check my edit, i think it's an .htaccess problem

Comment: @mrQubeMaster please check my edit, i'm pretty sure it's an .htaccess problem ( that i don't know what to put on it )

Comment: are you using a framework? how does your .htaccess look like? did you manualy write the rule to remove the .html part?

Answer (score 2):

have you got a .htaccess using re-write rules?  It might be specifying a different path on your live domain than your local server

Comment: Please check my edit, i think that's where my problem come from

Comment: to follow won from @mrQubeMaster without knowing the structure (i.e.) file paths of your domiain etc I couldn't answer precisely.  Essentially if it's working locally but not live it's because you have different file paths e.g. you might have your pages locally on localhost so everything is at the root (/page 1) but usually on a live server there are extra folders in the path.  Have a look at the two and see what's different, or as suggested post some more information about your htaccess and the structure (eg framework) of your project

Comment: or, just use fully qualified domains in the link which will work (but doesn't teach you to understand and solve the problem)

Answer (score 0):

You have to prepend those href with your domain.
For example,

```
http://www.yourWebSite.com/page1
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use it without slash so that it will pick the base url automatically.

```
<a href="page2">Page2</a>
```